# Using sagetex with preamble

Tags: sagetex

I want to use Sage via `sagetex` in my TeX files.

It works.

But if I use a precompiled preamble and use it in the tex document with `%&preamble`
in the first line, the already computed sageoutputs are not used and I get the double questionary `??` again.

Does anybody know a solution still using the precompiled preamble?

Comment: What is a **precompiled preamble**?

Comment: Please provide a [minimal (non) working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228).